# How to update my DB document with new objects inside?

Tags: javascript, express

I try to update my DB document by adding `firstName` and `lastName` but when I use my function it actually overwrite everything. So for example my object looks like this now

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a5"),
    "email" : "user@user.com",
    "password" : "$2HbyP4.ts9O/zrjV5Pcd/Z28bhOb8oGas9wEG",
    "userData" : [ 
        {
            "role" : "user",
            "phone" : 747483245,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a6"),
            "address" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a7")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

but when I update it looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a5"),
    "email" : "user@user.com",
    "password" : "$2HbyP4.ts9O/zrjV5Pcd/Z28bhOb8oGas9wEG",
    "userData" : [ 
        {
            "firstName" : "First Name",
            "lastName" : "Last Name",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a6"),
            "address" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5b0df225287cc77612ed89a7")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

so I no longer have `role` and `phone` inside
here is my function

```
// Update user data
exports.update = function (req, res, next) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, req.body)
    .exec()
    .then(doc => res.json(doc))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
exports.update = function (req, res) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user._id, { $set: { firstName: req.body.firstName , lastName:req.body.lastName }}, {upsert:true},function(err,user){
        if(err){
            res.json(err);
        }else{
            res.json(user);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Even this way is doing the same thing. I want to update the objects that are already inserted and insert new ones if not but don't remove the existing and untouched

Comment: @SaurabhMistry it is still removing the old elements

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {

  const query = {_id: req.user._id},
    update = { $set: {
       "userData.$.firstName": req.body.firstName, 
       "userData.$.lastName": req.body.lastName }
    },
    options = { upsert:true };

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(query, update, options)
    .exec()
    .then(user => res.json(user))
    .catch(err => res.json(err));
}
```

Comment: "errmsg": "exception: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: userData.$.lastName"